# Where I add card detail to receive payment of subscribe user (customer) in Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe.net

I have done all like this but where is add parameter to add card detail to of subscribe details.

https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/quickstart

My code is:

Where I add card detail to receive payment of subscribe user (customer) in Stripe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subscriptions use the default payment source.  So when you [Create a Customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer), you just need to provide a `source`-argument.

Comment: Thanks korben,its my code its working fine
its my code its working fine
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("Your-key");
$token = \Stripe\Token::create(array(
"card"   => array(
"number"  => $number,
"exp_month" => $exp_month,
"exp_year"  => $exp_year,
"cvc"   => $cvc  
))
);
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
"description" => "Customer for Admin",
"email"   => "",
"source"   => $token->id));
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("Your - key");
$subcription = \Stripe\Subscription::create(array(
 "customer" => $customer->id,
 "plan" => "basic-monthly",
));
Thanks Again for your reply

Comment: Can you pull that out into a Gist or something?  I can't follow this.

Comment: I follow your link I added source Argument as defined. I upload my code becacuse it worknig fine